# Change the number of columns and rows in a grid as the number of items increase

Tags: css, css-grid

I have to design a responsive grid.
The grid should change based on the number of items (instead of the size of the screen).

From 5 to 6 items should be 2x3,
from 7 to 9 items should be 3x3,
from 10 to 12 items should be 3x4,
from 13 to 16 items should be 4x4,
and so on...

Is this something I can do using CSS Grid?

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```html
<main>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">

  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">
  </figure>

</main>
```

```css
main {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12rem, 1fr));
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  /* flex-basis: 12rem; */
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I've always used something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12rem, 1fr))` but that's not the approach I need here. I know I have to use `align-content: stretch` but I don't know if it is possible what I've asked. If that's not possible in pure CSS I'll have to do the math in JavaScript.

Comment: share this into your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit columns creation can do this. You can consider `nth-child()`/`nth-last-child()` to create a new column when you reach a specific number of columns:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.container > :nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(n + 5) ~ :nth-child(3) { 
 grid-column: 3;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(n + 10) ~ :nth-child(4) { 
 grid-column: 4;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(n + 17) ~ :nth-child(5) { 
 grid-column: 5;
}

.container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```