# Dynamic Tile create and Adjust in Available Width

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, responsive-design

I want to create a dynamic tile(div) based on number of users are available.
Like it is happen in microsoft team meetings.
Example -
when there is only user then div occupy full screen.
[image]

When there are two users then both the divs should get 50% width like
[image]

When there are 3 users then divs should occupy 25%,25% and 50% area of screen. Like
[image]

When there ate four, five and six user then it will occupy space as -

[image]

And so on. So the dynamic tile (div) can adjust the UI automatically atleast upto 12-16 tiles.

This also needs to be responsive.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61197351/8620333

Comment: Similar - for a Zoom layout [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647196/creating-a-zoom-like-dynamic-gallery-view-in-css-html/65654429#65654429

Comment: is it necessary for cms?
i can do it

Answer (score -1):

**I made one to three users.
This is an example. using the current logic, you can do the rest yourself.
good luck.**

```js
var numUsers = $('#xusersx .user').length;
$('#xusersx').addClass('nowusers-' + numUsers);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
#xusersx {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#xusersx>.user {
    border: solid 4px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-1>.user {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-2>.user, #xusersx.nowusers-3>.user {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3 {
    width: 50%;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3>.user:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xusersx">
<div class="user"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var numUsers = $('#xusersx .user').length;
$('#xusersx').addClass('nowusers-' + numUsers);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
#xusersx {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#xusersx>.user {
    border: solid 4px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-1>.user {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-2>.user, #xusersx.nowusers-3>.user {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3 {
    width: 50%;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3>.user:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xusersx">
<div class="user"></div>
<div class="user"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var numUsers = $('#xusersx .user').length;
$('#xusersx').addClass('nowusers-' + numUsers);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
#xusersx {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#xusersx>.user {
    border: solid 4px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-1>.user {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-2>.user, #xusersx.nowusers-3>.user {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 200px;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3 {
    width: 50%;
}
#xusersx.nowusers-3>.user:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xusersx">
<div class="user"></div>
<div class="user"></div>
<div class="user"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution you will have to change the CSS if you want to add more users. The intended question was, to be able to add N amount of users and for it to work